# how to change cpu frequency governor type in code

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, cpu

I want to change CPU governor type (currently ondemand) to interactive.
I know how to change it using sysfs (echo to "scaling_governors").
But I want to change it in code. 
How/Where can I do it?

Thanks,
Sharon.

Comment: In what language?  And is there a good reason that your code can't write to sysfs?

Comment: I want to know what is the best practice for doing that. For example if vendor what to change the policy.
language, I suppose it would be "c".
I want to change this parameter at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Type of governor can be chosen in defconfig. It directy effects on cpufreq.h.
In cpufreq.h the definition of CPUFREQ_DEFAULT_GOVERNOR is set to relevant governor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out -:

```
sudo  bash -c ‘for ((i=0; i<$(nproc);i++)); do cpufreq-set -c $i -g interactive; done’
```